# Import successful when file manually deleted

Tags: import, files-and-directories

Apparently Import keeps an imported file in the cache and doesn't complain for some time if a file is deleted manually from the system and then it is imported. If the file is deleted from within Mathematica, then it does complain. Here is a minimal working example:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}};

Export["test.mc", Compress@list, "String"]

Uncompress@Import["./test.mc"]
```

This is successful. Now delete the file manually from your Directory and check that it is indeed deleted:

```
FileNames["./test.mc"]

>>> {}
```

Now importing again works without error:

```
Uncompress@Import["./test.mc"]

>>> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}}
```

Now deleting the file within Mathematica:

```
DeleteFile["./test.mc"]

Uncompress@Import["./test.mc"]

>>> Import::nffil: File not found during Import. >>
Uncompress::string: String expected at position 1 in Uncompress[$Failed]. >>
Uncompress[$Failed]
```

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Apparently clearing the SystemCache and waiting some time, works.

This is important for me because I have a function that detects if a file has been deleted using Check[Import[....]].
This means that my function doesn't work if the file is recently deleted in my system.

I am using Mathematica 9.0.1 in Debian Linux 3.2.65.

Comment: Does checking with `FileExistsQ` instead of `Import` work?

Comment: Also, can't reproduce behavior (MMA 10.0.0, Windows 8.1 64-bit), I just get `Import::nffil` immediately.

Comment: Let me guess, you're on OSX?

Comment: No, I'm on Linux Debian 3.2.65.

Comment: Yes, @2012rcampion, changing the check would be enough. I just find this a very strange behavior.

Comment: My guess is that it's OS or filesystem related.  For example, it may put the file 'in the trash' by marking files as deleted so they don't display in Nautilus, but not actually moving them.  I had a problem like this when solving a problem on my parent's iMac, but I have never encountered such a problem on Debian.  Try using `rm` on the file to delete it (or `ls -a` to check if the file is actually deleted).

Comment: Yes, probably it is something like that. I will check more carefully. By the way, I am using Mathematica 9.0.1